# Configure a local build plan with Harbormaster and Drydock

Tags: continuous-deployment, phabricator

I'm trying to create a simple build plan using *Harbormaster* and *Drydock*:

1. Whenever a commit is made the build plan `Deployment` should be triggered. This can be easily done with *Harold*.
2. The build plan `Deployment` has some build steps which run a command.

I know *Drydock* and *Harbormaster* are prototypes so it seems there is no much documentation.

So first I've created a build plan and added two build steps for testing:

- `Lease Host` build step with `localhost` as name and `linux` as platform
- `Run Command` build step with `php /var/www/ci/test.php` as command and `localhost` as host

But the error message after a manual start was:

```
exception 'Exception' with message 'Lease has been broken!' in /var/www/phabricator/src/applications/drydock/storage/DrydockLease.php:172
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/phabricator/src/applications/drydock/storage/DrydockLease.php(198): DrydockLease::waitForLeases(Array)
#1 /var/www/phabricator/src/applications/harbormaster/step/HarbormasterLeaseHostBuildStepImplementation.php(32): DrydockLease->waitUntilActive()
#2 /var/www/phabricator/src/applications/harbormaster/worker/HarbormasterTargetWorker.php(52): HarbormasterLeaseHostBuildStepImplementation->execute(Object(HarbormasterBuild), Object(HarbormasterBuildTarget))
#3 /var/www/phabricator/src/infrastructure/daemon/workers/PhabricatorWorker.php(91): HarbormasterTargetWorker->doWork()
#4 /var/www/phabricator/src/infrastructure/daemon/workers/storage/PhabricatorWorkerActiveTask.php(162): PhabricatorWorker->executeTask()
#5 /var/www/phabricator/src/infrastructure/daemon/workers/PhabricatorTaskmasterDaemon.php(22): PhabricatorWorkerActiveTask->executeTask()
#6 /var/www/libphutil/src/daemon/PhutilDaemon.php(183): PhabricatorTaskmasterDaemon->run()
#7 /var/www/libphutil/scripts/daemon/exec/exec_daemon.php(125): PhutilDaemon->execute()
#8 {main}
```

Could anybody give me some hints how to run commands on localhost with *Harbormaster* and *Drydock*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I have not created any resource through *Drydock*. Here how you can get execute a command with *Harbormaster* and *Drydock*:

1. Create a *Drydock Blueprint* (e.g. `Blueprint 4711`).
2. Create a *Passphrase SSH Private Key* for *Drydock* which can be used to access your local host through SSH (e.g. `K123`).
3. Create a *Drydock Resource* through the CLI for your local host:

   ```
   ./bin/drydock create-resource --blueprint 4711 --name localhost --attributes host=localhost,platform=linux,remote=true,port=22,path=/var/drydock,credential=123
   ```
4. Create a *Harbormaster Build Plan*.
5. Add a *Build Step* (`Lease Host`) to your *Build Plan*, use your *Drydock Blueprint* as `Artifact` and `linux` as `Platform`.
6. Add a second *Build Step* to your *Build Plan* (`Run Command`) with the command you want and your *Drydock Blueprint* as `Host`.

Using the server itself for CD/CI might be only an option for small installations.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in this awesome guide I published on Wikibooks to cover most of the aspects. If you want to understand how Almanac, Drydock and Harbormaster interact each other:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Phabricator_Administrator%27s_Handbook/Continuous_integration

Of course you will find some screenshots and nice schemas like this one:

[image: Phabricator continuous integration schema]

This guide somehow expands the official documentation and, moreover, it includes a troubleshooting section (that covers your exact problem!).

Have a good reading!